# How to use a properties file in Spring beans XML file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I have some properties files that I'd like to make available in the Spring XML config files. For example, in `hello.xml`:

```
<bean id="theFoo" class="learnspring.Foo">
    <property name="color" value="${foo.color}"/>
</bean>
```

In Java code:

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hello.xml");
File props = new File("path/to/hello.properties");
File moreProps = new File("path/to/more.properties");
// What to do here?
Foo foo = (Foo)ac.getBean("theFoo");
System.out.println(foo.getColor());
```

In `hello.properties`:

```
foo.color = blue
```

How do I make the properties files available to the Spring object definitions?

**Update**

I'm porting some old Spring code. (Version 2.5) It looked sort of like this:

```
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(xmlFile));
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
cfg.setLocations(new Resource[] {
    new ClassPathResource(propsResourcePath),
    new FileSystemResource(propsFile)) });

cfg.postProcessBeanFactory(factory);
new GenericApplicationContext(factory);
```

This code was marked deprecated, and I was having other problems, so I tried to port it to the new way.

Comment: Perhaps `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` ? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Comment: That shows how to hard code a path to properties, in the XML file, but what if I have some `File` objects in Java code?

Answer (score 2):

You Could read the more.properties in java code with the help of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Not sure why you would really need to read as File Object.

In hello.xml file

```
<!-- Loading all properties files from classpath -->
    <bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:hello.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:more.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="theFoo" class="learnspring.Foo">
        <property name="color" value="${foo.color}"/>
        <property name="shape" value="${foo.shape}"/>
    </bean>
```

In hello.properties file

```
 foo.color=blue
```

In more.properties file

```
foo.shape=square
```

In Java Code

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hello.xml");
Foo foo = (Foo) ctx.getBean("theFoo");
System.out.println("Color : " + foo.getColor() +" Shape : " + foo.getShape());
```

Comment: The File objects are because I'm working with legacy code.

Comment: ok. were you trying to see something like below , without using spring?
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

if you need these properties to be loaded to Foo object, you can autowire it and set the values.

Comment: I'm porting older Spring code. I added it to question under "Update".

Answer (score -1):

In case you also want to loop through the bean data and display their contents on your jsp.

*hello.xml*

```
<bean id="productManager" class="springapp.service.SimpleProductManager">
    <property name="products">
        <list>
            <ref bean="product1"/>
            <ref bean="product2"/>
            <ref bean="product3"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="product1" class="springapp.domain.Product">
    <property name="description" value="Lamp"/>
    <property name="price" value="5.75"/>
</bean>

<bean id="product2" class="springapp.domain.Product">
    <property name="description" value="Table"/>
    <property name="price" value="75.25"/>
</bean>
...
```

*hello.jsp*

```
<c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod">
  <c:out value="${prod.description}"/>
  $<c:out value="${prod.price}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Reference: [Spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part4.html)

Comment: My question has nothing to do with JSP. I'm trying to use the `${property}` syntax in the spring config file, to define the beans.