# @Value property injection not working in GenericFilterBean Spring

Tags: spring, filter, servlet-filters

I am trying to inject a property from a property file. I am using Spring 4.3 version.
The property file is present in src/main/resources folder.

In Web.xml I have the below configuration for filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My Custom Filter class:

```
public class SecurityFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

     @Value("${url.value}")
     private String url;     

     ...         

     }
```

In Spring Application context XML file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:authentication.properties"/>
<bean id="securityFilter" class="com.example.SecurityFilter"/>
```

But when starting the server it throws an exception that it is unable to create the bean

```
Error creating bean with name 'securityFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'url.value' in string value "${url.value}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Half of your code is with Annotation and half is in XML. Try using Annotation completly. Mark the class with @Component and ensure that it's package is included in context component scanner at your app servlet file. Ensure that property file is having the required entry and you need not write the bean explicitly.
Uptate:
Ensure to have properties file in the classpath.

Comment: Hi Jajikanth, Thanks for the reply. I tried annotating the class with @Component annotation but still it throws the same error. It unable to map the property to string.Could not resolve placeholder 'url' in string value "${url.value}"

Comment: One possibility is your properties file is not included in the classpath. Are you sure about it? Please share the screenshot of your project structure.My answer in below link may give more idea. But it doest use Annotation.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710016/how-to-use-a-properties-file-in-spring-beans-xml-file/43768787#43768787

Comment: @Jaijikanth you were correct. The property file was not in the classpath. Now the issue got resolved and I am able to load the property file.